# Inserting temporary content within snippets in "Visual Studio Code"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Within Visual Studio Code 1.7.2, I am able to generate a quick list of HTML data with the following snippet, followed by pressing TAB...

```
ul>li*5>h3+div
```

That will generate this list...

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3></h3>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3></h3>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3></h3>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3></h3>
        <div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3></h3>
        <div></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But how can I prepopulate every `<h3></h3>` to say `<h3>tite</h3>`, and every `<div></div>` to say `<div>content</div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VScode uses [emmet](http://emmet.io) for this, so the input text would be:

```
ul>li*5>h3{title}+div{content}
```

which will expand to:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>title</h3>
        <div>content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>title</h3>
        <div>content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>title</h3>
        <div>content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>title</h3>
        <div>content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>title</h3>
        <div>content</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Here's additional documentation of the Emmet abbreviation syntax](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/)

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks for the emmet information as well.